# Separate characters and numbers following specific rules

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to distinguish flight numbers.

```
Example: 
flightno = "FR556"
split_data = flightno.upcase.match(/([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)/)
first  = split_data[1] # FR
second = split_data[1] # 556
```

I then go on to query the database to find an airline based on the FR in this example and apply some logic with the result which is Ryanair.

My problem is when the flight number might be:

```
flightno = "U21920"
split_data = flightno.upcase.match(/([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)/)
first  = split_data[1] # U
second = split_data[1] # 21920
```

i basically want first to be U2 not just U. This is used to search the database of airlines by their IATA code in this case is U2

****EDIT**
In the interest of clarity i made some mistakes in terminology when asking my question. Due to the complexities of booking reference numbers, the input is taken from whatever the passenger provides. For an easyJet flight for example, the passenger may input EZY1920 or U21920 only the airline provides either so the passenger is ignorant really.

"EZY" = ICAO
"U2" = IATA

I take the input from the user and try to separate the ICAO or IATA from the flight number "1920" but there is no way of determining that without searching the database or separating the input which i feel is cumbersome from a user experience point of view.

Using a regex to separate characters from numbers works until the user inputs an IATA as part of their flight number (the passenger won't know the difference) and as you can see in the example above this confuses the regex.**

The trouble is i cant think of any other pattern with flight numbers. They always have at least two characters made up of just letters or a mixture of a letter and a number and can be 3 characters in length. The numbers part can be as short as 1 but can also be as long as 4 - always numbers.

****edit** 
As has been mentioned in the comments, there is no fixed size however one thing that is always true (at least so far) is the first character will always be a letter regardless if it is ICAO or IATA.
After considering every bodies input so far i'm wondering if searching the database and returning airlines with an IATA or ICAO that matches the first two letters provided by the user (U2), (FR), (EZ) might be one way to go, however this is subject to obvious problems should an ICAO or IATA be released that matches another airline, for example "EZY" & "EZT". This is not future proof and i'm looking for better ruby or regex solutions.**

Appreciate your input.

**EDIT**

I have answered my own question below. While other answers provide a solution for handling some conditions they would fall down if the flight number began with a number so i worked out a crass but to date stable way to analyse the string for digits and then work out if it is an ICAO or IATA from that.

Comment: @Wiktor As he said, it's not fixed. PO: Any chance you could match the flight number against a list of all possible ICAO codes?

Comment: If your all flight numbers contains 2 digit first code. you can seperate it by first 2 digits.

Comment: `/([A-Za-z][A-Za-z\d])(\d+)/`

Comment: Are you asking what is the general pattern for flight number or are you asking how match a digit as well if it starts with only one letter? If it's the former, that would be off topic for SO.

Comment: If you do not know how to separate the first from the second, how can a machine do that? Please provide clear specifications.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have updated my OP to be a little more specific.

Comment: @ShefaleeChaudhary thank you, i am considering this and then running a search against both IATA and ICAO for a match but this is not very future proof

Comment: After your edit, I think the best is to change the UI or the way the information is input by the user. The code and flight numbers should be provided as separate entities. Otherwise, you need to get the list of all IATA/ICAO codes, create an alternation group like `\A(U23|U2|U)` (note the length and order), and then add the `(\d+)\z`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a fairly crass solution that seems to be working in all scenarios i can throw at it to date. I wanted to make this available to anybody else that might find it useful?

The general rule of thumb for flight codes/numbers seems to be:

IATA: two characters made up of any combination letters and digits
ICAO: three characters made up of letters only (to date)

With that in mind we should be able to work out if we need to search the database by IATA or ICAO depending on the condition of the first three characters.

**First we take the flight number and convert to uppercase**

```
string  = "U21920".upcase
```

**Next we analyse the first three characters to check for any numbers.**

```
first_three = string[0,3] # => U21
```

**Is there a digit in first_three?**

```
if first_three =~ /\d/ # => true
iata = first_three[0,2] # => If true lets get rid of the last character
# Now we go to the database searching IATA (U2)

search = Airline.where('iata LIKE ?', "#{iata}%") # => Starts with search, just in case
```

**Otherwise if there isnt a digit found in the string**

```
else
 icao = string.match(/([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)/)
 search = Airline.where('icao LIKE ?', "#{icao[1]}%")
```

This seems to work for the random flight numbers ive tested it with today from a few of the major airport live departure/arrival boards. Its an interesting problem because some airlines issue tickets with either an ICAO or IATA code as part of the flight number which means passengers won't know any different, not to mention, some airports provide flight information in their own format so assumign there isnt a change to the ICAO and IATA build then the above should work.

Here is an example script you can run

**test.rb**

```
puts "What is your flight number?"
string  = gets.upcase
first_three = string[0,3]
puts "Taking first three from #{string} is #{first_three}"

if first_three =~ /\d/         # Calling String's =~ method.
 puts "The String #{first_three} DOES have a number in it."
 iata = first_three[0,2]
 search = Airline.where('iata LIKE ?', "#{iata}%")
 puts "Searching Airlines starting with IATA #{iata} = #{search.count}"
 puts "Found #{search.first.name} from IATA #{iata}"
else
 puts "The String #{first_three} does not have a number in it."
 icao = string.match(/([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)/)
 search = Airline.where('icao LIKE ?', "#{icao[1]}%")
 puts "Searching Airlines starting with ICAO #{icao[1]} = #{search.count}"
 puts "Found #{search.first.name} from IATA #{icao[1]}"
end
```

**Airline**

```
Airline(id: integer, name: string, iata: string, icao: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime )
```

stick this in your lib folder and run

> rails runner lib/test.rb

Obviously you can remove all of the puts statements to get straight to the result. I'm using rails runner to include access to my Airline model when running the script.

Answer (score 1):

A solution I think of is that you match your given flight number against a complete list of ICAO/IATA codes: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/airport-codes/master/data/airport-codes.csv

Spending some time with google might give you a more appropriate list.

Then use the first three characters (if that is the maximum) of your flight number to find a match within the icao codes. If you find one, you will know where to seperate your string.

Here a minimal ugly example that should set you on a track. Feel free to update!

```
ICAOCODES = %w(FR DEU U21) # grab your data here

def retrieve_flight_information(flightnumber)
  ICAOCODES.each do |icao|
    co = flightnumber.match(icao).to_s
    if co.length > 0
      # airline
      puts co
      # flight number
      puts flightnumber.gsub(co,'')
    end
  end
end

retrieve_flight_information("FR556")
#=> FR
#=> 556
retrieve_flight_information("U21214123")
#=> U21
#=> 214123
```

The biggest flaw lies in using `.gsub()` as it might mess up your flightnumber in case it looks like this: `"FR21413FR2"`
However you will find plenty of solutions to this problem on so.

*As mentioned in the comments, a list of icao codes is not what you are looking for. But what is relevant here, is that you somehow need a list of strings that you can securely compare against.*

Comment: It seems that the OP uses IATA code, not ICAO code because ICAO code always starts with 3 alphabetical characters. An IATA code, however, can have 2 to 3 alphanumeric characters designating airline, followed by 1 to 4 numeric characters designating flight. Neither the airline part nor the flight part has fixed length.

Comment: Alright, good to know. Never got in touch with them I must admit. I'll try to generalize the answer. Thank you

Comment: I have to admit that a complete list is necessary because neither the airline part nor the flight part has fixed length.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time, i have updated my OP because i did not mention the users input could be either an ICAO or IATA so i must match the input to the possibility of either and apply further logic once the airline has been matched this way.

@TheF It seems i may have to take the first two characters of the input and search my airline database for either the first two characters of the IATA or ICAO and hopefully this won't return multiple matches. I'm testing this now but still don't like it and feels a crass work around? Thoughts?